# absolute extrema right before the open interval

Tags: calculus

If we have a function y = x^2 on the interval (-1,1), why can we not say that the absolute max occurs at a value say +- 0.9, or something similar? Why can we not define a new number to test.

Why must it be only critical numbers and endpoints, when clearly their is an absolute max at really close to f(1).

Comment: Instead we're supposed to just say, "the absolute max does not exist". Like we're ignoring the values there. Why can't we use something like the limit, to say that there is a absolute max really close to that value, its just not at that specific value.

Comment: On the interval $(-1,1)$, it is always true that $x^2 < 1$.  However, if you give me *any* number $M<1$, I can find some value of $x$ such that $M < x^2 < 1$.  Thus $M$ cannot be a maximum.  Therefore this function has no maximum on that interval.  It does, however, have a supremum of 1.

Comment: Ok that makes since. So the supremum is the 0.9999....9 number? The number infinity close to 1 correct?

Comment: No, the supremum is exactly 1.

Comment: If the set of number is the values of the range, then 1 is not included. So the largest range value is 0.999999....9, which should be the supremum(largest value in set). Are you rounding it to 1?

Comment: @fxkrait: It turns out that it isn't *rounding* but the number is actually equal to $1$.

Comment: This requires knowledge of supremum and infimum. An answer will come soon.

Comment: So basically 0.999999....9 is equivalent to 1? I get that, but I thought since that 1 was explicitly defined as not on the interval, we are never allowed to say 1.

Comment: Ok yes, I'm just learning about these supremum and infimum.

Comment: When you write $0.999\dotso 9$, you are writing a number that has a finite number of 9s after the decimal place.  This number is not 1.  However, when you write $0.999\dotso$, you are writing a number which has an infinite number of 9s after the decimal point.  That number is exactly equal to 1.

Comment: So basically, even though f(1) is not part of the domain, we can still say that the supremum is f(1)? My only point for saying that the supremum is f(0.999...) is to keep it within the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x^2$ does not assume an absolute maximum on  the open interval $(-1,1)$ because no matter how close you get to $x=1$ you can still get closer and get a larger value without actually hitting $x=1$
That is why they introduce the concept of supremum,  which in this case  is $1$

That simply says if you pick any number $y <1$, you can find an $x\in (-1,1)$ such that $x^2>y$